# Stack Overflow shows gravatar pic of outdated email address

Tags: support, gravatar

I have a Stack Overflow account since about 2012. Back then, I had registered with an ancient email address which is not in use any more. I have updated my Stack Overflow profile accordingly. Even though the old email is not visible to me anywhere on Stack Overflow any more, I still see that Stack Overflow retrieves my gravatar image from the outdated email address. I know that because the md5 hash of the Gravatar image URL matches my old email address.

I do not have any access to the old email any more, as the domain had been cancelled. How do I resolve that problem? From where does Stack Overflow still fetch the old email?

Answer (score 7):

Your gravatar image is based off a *legacy* per-site email field that you can’t change. Nor can moderators, unfortunately. See [this post on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341930/140890):

> This is a vestigial field; it's still used for unregistered users, Gravatar, and maybe a few other things I forget... But it's no longer directly editable except on Area51.

You can [contact support](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) to request it be cleared.